# Reasons to decrease the Content length in Jmeter script?

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, load-testing

At the time of the recording i am getting the content length into the response headers like :**Content-Length: 17675** while after the scripting same script Content length reduced like : **Content-Length: 13620**

While i am unable to get the expected output i have already verify the HTTP headers as well as input data.

Answer (score 0):

As per [4 Things You Should Never Do with Your JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/4-things-you-should-never-do-your-jmeter-script)

> **Don’t run the script exactly as you recorded it**
>
> After recording your script, there is still some work to do before you run it. It’s necessary to correlate variables, parameterize and add elements, to faithfully simulate users.
>
> Here is a short list of general samplers and modifications that you’ll need to consider:
>
> - Add a Cookie Manager - pay attention whether you need to erase the cookies on each iteration or not (you can set this with a checkbox in the sampler).
> - Add a HTTP Request Default Sampler to define the server, port and protocol in just one place. If you erase this specification from your requests, you will be able to change your test environment easier.
> - Review which Response Assertions you need to add.
> - Parametrize Hosts in the Headers to make your script more flexible and supportable.
>
> There may be other samplers you need to add depending on your scripts, like Cache Manager, counters, regular expressions, Authoritation Managers or CSV Data Set Config (if you need to read a data file). All of these actions will help you to develop your script in a way that simulates real user actions, which is critical for obtaining reasonable results.

My expectation is that your script basically silently fails somewhere during replaying, i.e. virtual user not logging in or navigating to another page. Inspect response details using "Response Data" tab of the View Results Tree listener.

[image: JMeter View Results Tree]

If you are not seeing the page you expected to see - something is wrong with your script and you need to amend it, most probably implement **correlation** using [JMeter Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)

Also don't expect headers to be exactly the same, for example [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date), [Last-Modified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified), [If-Unmodified-Since](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Unmodified-Since), etc. headers will always be **dynamic** therefore expecting headers to be byte-to-byte equal to what you've recorded is something highly unlikely to happen.

As an alternative I would rather suggest going for [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) and [Size Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Size_Assertion) and checking only **essential** parts of the response.